# ¿Por qué obtengo el error de que no está declarada la variable i?

Tags: mql4

Estoy tratando de hacer un código en mql4 para poder guardar los datos de un indicador en un archivo pero obtengo el error de que la variable i no está declarada.
El código es el siguiente:

```
void OnTick()
  {
      for(int i=10000; i>0; i--)
     {
      double lotGreen = iCustom(NULL,0,"..\\Indicators\\Indicator.ex4","","EURUSD",0,3,14,80,
      clrBlack,clrCrimson,clrLimeGreen,"",false,1,i);
      
      if(lotGreen!= EMPTY_VALUE){
        Print("Lleno", lotGreen); 
      }
      else{
        Print("Vacío", lotGreen);
      }

      Print("Valor del indicador = ",lotGreen, "\n", "Valor de i = ",i);

     }
     
     //static double LastLow;
     //static double LastHigh;
     
     if (i != EMPTY_VALUE)
     {
       // create a file name
       string data = "DataIndicator.csv";
       
       // open the file for reading and writing, as CSV format, ANSI mode
       int dataindicator=FileOpen(data, FILE_READ|FILE_WRITE|FILE_CSV|FILE_ANSI);
       
       // go to the end of the file 
       FileSeek(dataindicator, 0, SEEK_END);
       
       // Append time, high and low to the file content
       FileWrite(dataindicator,"Time Stamp", Time[1], "Short", i, "Long", i + 100);
       
       // Close the file
       FileClose(dataindicator);
       
       // Assign the current values for the next time
       //LastHigh=High[1];
       //LastLow=Low[1];
     
     }
  }
```

El valor que quiero almacenar en el archivo es jústamente el valor de i, que es la variable que me devuelve el valor del buffer del indicador.

¿Alguien sabe como resolver el problema?

Comment: No estoy seguro si aplique a este lenguaje, pero en C++, C#, Java y otros lenguajes es así: lo que está en el for solo existe dentro del for. Para poder acceder a la variable tienes que declararla fuera del ciclo.

Comment: ¿Pero si la declaro fuera del ciclo no puedo obtener los valores de la función no? Es decir, yo quiero en el archivo los valores de la i que está dentro del propio ciclo, no se si me explico